# request for the JavaScript regex for pattern

Tags: javascript

following is the string i have and i would like to read the number "10" (last inside the () )using regex. I am using Javascript.

"test me 234 and the (another) and test  (10)"

Comment: A good resource to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var str = "test me 234 and the (another) and test (10)";
result = str.match(/\((\d+)\)$/);
console.log(result[1]);
```